# UISegmentedControl text programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have created a UISegmentedControl with two segments using the interface builder (from storyboard), but I would like to set the text of the two segments programmatically.  I want to do this because I am using NSLocalizedString for all of my buttons, labels, titles etc.
I create all the stuff in interface builder and then I add text programmatically.
I have manage to make every item to work that way but I cannot find a way to add text to my UISegmentedControl.

Is there any way to do that?
I ma trying to use the following but because the segmented control is already created in the interface builder it does not work.

```
[segmentedControl initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Title 1", @"Title 1"),NSLocalizedString(@"Title 2", @"Title 2"), nil]];
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 198, accepted):

```
[segmentedControl setTitle:<YourLocalizedString> forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: segmentedControl.setTitle("stuff", forSegmentAtIndex: 0) - swift version

Comment: Thanks... but also, another one of those dumb Apple conventions that'd be better being `segmentedControl.titles = ["title","title","title"]` imo

Answer (score 17):

The correct answer for people using **SWIFT 4** would be

```
segmentedControl.setTitle("Your Title", forSegmentAt: 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) to assign the title to your segments of the segmented control.

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Updated :

***Use below simple code to set UISegmentControl title programatically;***

*//.h file:*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
```

*// .m file:*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Love It" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Hate It" forSegmentAtIndex:1];        
     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Ehh" forSegmentAtIndex:2];
}
```